# How to add second value of 2 dimensional array together?

Tags: php

I have a two dimensional array.

```
arr["id1"][10]
arr["id2"][20]
```

How to i add the second value of each item together.

e.g. 10 + 20 = 30 (return)

I need to run through all items in the array and add the second value together.

Comment: This is a really odd situation, how'd you end up with an array like this?

Comment: Could you add few more sample datad and what is your expected result, its a little hard to tell what exactly you want with just two datas.

Comment: Well, i am "hacking out" a shopping cart. Id1 refers to the product unique id, 10 refers to the amount of items added.

Comment: Copy and paste my answer, it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = 0;

foreach($arr as $v) {
  $res += $v;
}
```

like this you add the value of each item to $res

Comment: Seems that i think too complicated into things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is sooo weird, but I'm in the mood for some puzzle solving.

```
<?php

$odd_data["id1"][10] = 'Food item one';
$odd_data["id2"][20] = 'Food item two';

echo add_the_second_array_keys_of_the_array($odd_data);

function add_the_second_array_keys_of_the_array($odd_data)
{
   $total = 0;
    foreach($odd_data as $id)
    {
        foreach($id as $number=>$the_message)
        {
            $total += $number;   
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer which actually does what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function collapse($array){
  return array_keys($array)[0];
}
print array_sum(array_map('collapse', $arr));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = array();

function sort($arr) {
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i+2)
    {
        $result[$i] = $arr[$i] + $arr[$i+1];
    }
}
```

this will have result storing the summing values. (the keys's although will jump by 2 e.g 1, 3, 5 ...)

Comment: I think it possibly has to do with it not really being a solution to the OP's question.  You're not taking into account his special case, the function is an infinite loop, and the function doesn't return anything meaningful in regard to what the question asked, so it's kind of unclear what to do with it.